# Angular - How to add parameters to ng-src

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having an iframe with `ng-src` where I pass the value of the url, I would like to add to that url parameters, specifically I would like to add this:

```
&controls=0&showinfo=0
```

This is how my html looks like:

```
<iframe ng-src="{{article.external_media[0].url | safeUrl }}"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would  manipulate url in custom function, something like

```
$scope.getUrl = function(){ 
    var url=new Url($scope.article.external_media[0].url | $scope.safeUrl);
    url.searchParams.append('controls',0);
    url.searchParams.append('showinfo',0);
    return url.toString();
}


<iframe ng-src="{{::getUrl()}}"></iframe>
```